# gnuplot cluster the x range for stacked histograms

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following code that generates a stacked histogram:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set term postscript eps enhanced color
#set output 'stacked-hist.eps'
set output ARG1.'.eps'

set title ARG1
set key top left outside horizontal autotitle columnhead

#set xtics rotate by 90 offset 0,-5 out nomirror
set autoscale x
set ytics out nomirror

set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked
set xlabel "Degree of node"

plot ARG1 using 2, '' using 3:xtic(1)
```

This results into the following: (Because the xrange is 0:5000)
[image: Stacked histogram for a long x-range]

What I would like to have is following (In the input data, I don't have many datapoints for every X, So I would like to see the clusters of histograms as shown below:
[image]

Is there way to do it in gnuplot ?
Is there a formal name for such stacked histograms ? (grouped stacked histograms)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? It's not clear how to interpret your example graph, hence not clear how to reproduce it. Are there no datapoints in 200 < x < 1000? Or are those points placed in the bin at 200 or 1000?

Comment: there may be a few data points between 200 and 1000 but I want to ignore them. Is it possible in gnuplot ?

Answer (score 0):

From your answer to my comment it sounds as if you just want to skip values that are below some number. If this is all you need, it's pretty simple. First let's make a table of random numbers and make a histogram plot of it (I'll skip the style setup, but I'm using yours):

`set table
set out 'rand.dat'
plot rand(0)
unset table
plot 'rand.dat'`

That gives us this:

[image: Normal histogram plot]

If we want to skip drawing histogram boxes for values below a certain value, say 0.4, we can just do this:

`c = 0.4
plot 'rand.dat' using ($2 > c ? $2 : NaN)`

which gets us this:

[image: Histogram with gaps]

If I still don't understand what you're trying to do, sorry. Feel free to enlighten me, and I'll try again.